# GoogleMaps and for

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this google map:

```
<?php
//Conexion db

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM routes"); 

?> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<style type="text/css"> 
  html { height: 100% } 
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } 
  #map_canvas { height: 100% } 
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=es"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 


window.onload = function () {
  var options = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.84706, -2.944336),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);


  <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++){
            $icao = mysql_result($query, $i, 'from');
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM airports WHERE icao='$icao'");
            $latitude = mysql_result($query, 0, 'latitude');
            $longitude = mysql_result($query, 0, 'longitude'); 
            $city = mysql_result($query, 0, 'city'); 
        ?> 
  var Airport1 = '<h3 align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $icao; ?> - <?php echo $city; ?></h3>';
  var image = 'http://i46.tinypic.com/33zbm09.png';
  var latLonCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLonCenter,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: image,
    title: '<?php echo $icao; ?> - <?php echo $city; ?>',
    Airport1: Airport1
  });



    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: Airport1
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      var n = 1;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "",
        maxWidth: 320,  
        zIndex: n 
      });

      infowindow.setContent(this.Airport1);
      infowindow.setZIndex(n++);  // superpone el último infowindows
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE from='$icao'");


    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++){
    $destination = mysql_result($query, $i, 'to');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM airports WHERE icao='$destiantion'");
    $latitudeD = mysql_result($query, 0, 'latitude');
    $longitudeD = mysql_result($query, 0, 'longitude'); 
    ?>

    var PolyLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    var polyCords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
    new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitudeD; ?>, <?php echo $longitudeD; ?>)
    ];


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


    PolyLine.setPath(polyCords);

    PolyLine.setMap(map);
    });

<?php } } ?>



}
</script> 
  </head>

  <body> 
    <center><div id="map_canvas" style="width:850px; height:560px;"></div></center> 
  </body>
```

What happens is that it doesn´tshows me the polilyne. The idea is clicking on the marker to open a network of polylines to other marker. The marker is displayed without problems but when clicking on them the polylines don´t appear.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be using ajax. Clicking on the marker will have to load JSON data for the polyline. Also I noticed that you are loading coordinates via PHP query. I suggest you do this on a separate page where you will output it in JSON format then fetch it via ajax to display them to your map dynamically.